# MySql clips TIME values

Tags: mysql, database, time

### Background

We have a column of TIME data type to indicate elapsed time.

### Issue

When we try to insert a number of hours greater than 24, for example '25:00:00', MySQL clips this value down to '01:00:00', which is not what we want.

### Solution Attempted

The documentation suggests that we can use 'HHH:MM:SS' instead of 'HH:MM:SS' format (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.htm). That would probably solve our problem, but the documentation doesn't say how to do this.

Comment: I've never tried to do that, but my first guess would be maybe it has to do with "strict mode" preventing "invalid" dates.

Comment: Even HHH will exhibit the same behaviour ~840 hours; Why not store [int seconds]

Comment: @AlexK.The 840-hour limit should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INT UNSIGNED` to measure duration instead. For example, represent seconds as `INT UNSIGNED` if that is the "grain" for the time dimension.

Reasons:

- `INT` calculations are way simpler!
- My impression is that `TIME` is meant to indicate time of day, *not* duration.
- JDBC can't understand `TIME` values larger than 24 hours.
- Getting `TIME` to format as `HHH` instead of `HH` is undocumented and we couldn't figure it out.